# Which one is more appropriate, "many a time" or "many a times"?

Tags: phrases, word-usage, differences

I used to think that phrases starting with 'many a ' were notionally plural but singular in usage. So, which one is more appropriate here?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the singular is more correct. The plural sounds like a mistake by someone who had heard the phrase but had not really thought about its grammatical structure. A similar phenomenon is the popular "I could care less", where the speaker failed to consider the actual meaning of the words while simply trying to use the commonly known expression.

Answer (score 0):

I differ with Michael. He says the singular is "more correct". I say it is only singular which is correct. The plural is incorrect.

Comment: Your post reads more like a comment to @Michael's answer than an answer to the question which was already asked in this community.

Comment: To be honest, I too would not use the plural version whatsoever. One problem is that there is always going to be someone arguing that because some portion of people say something one way that it must be permissible. I was trying to be modest with my answer text. On the other hand, I did go on to explain that the plural version appears to have sprung from a mistake. Also, if you want to be technical, both are incorrect since "many" is plural by nature while "a" is singular. Are there not varying degrees of incorrectness in the realm of language and usage?

Comment: @Michael, language is language; it is not mathematics. Language has its own rules, peculiar rules. They may or may not prove correct on the touchstone of logic. The instant problem that we are discussing also presents one of such peculiarities of the English language. So, I again differ with you when you say, viewed technically, "both" are incorrect.